# C++ Difference between the sum of the squares of the first ten natural numbers and the square of the sum

Tags: c++

i wrote a code that calculates and outputs a difference between the sum of the squares of the first ten natural numbers and the square of the sum.

The problem is with function squareOfSum(). The function should return 3025 but it always returns 3024. Even if i try to put 100 into brackets i get 25502499 (25502500 is correct). No matter what number i put into brackets i always get the same problem.
What am I doing wrong?

[Here's a screenshot of my output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWSUP.png)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int sumOfSquares(int limit);
int squareOfSum(int limit);

int main()
{
    cout << sumOfSquares(10) << endl;
    cout << squareOfSum(10) << endl;
    cout << squareOfSum(10) - sumOfSquares(10) << endl;
}

int sumOfSquares(int limit)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<=limit; i++)
    {
        sum +=pow(i,2);
    }
    return sum;
}

int squareOfSum(int limit)
{
    int sum = 0, square = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<=limit; i++)
    {
        sum +=i;
    }
    square = pow(sum,2);
    return square;
}
```

Comment: This error not reproduced for gcc 4.8.2: `$ g++ square.cpp -o square
./square 
385
3025
2640`

Comment: It shows 385 3025 2640 for me, which is correct. Maybe you accidentally fixed it when copying it to stackoverflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `pow` is a function that works with floating point numbers. Optimizations might lead to rounding errors or truncation during implicit coversion to int. Replace `pow(i, 2)` with `i*i` and you'll get pure integer arithmetic and thus exact results.

Comment: I changed square = pow(sum,2) into square = sum*sum; and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std;

int main()

{
int higher_limit = 100;
int SquaresOfSum = 0;
int SumOfSquares = 0,count=0;
for(int i=1;i<=higher_limit;i++){
    count += i;
    SumOfSquares += pow(i,2);
    }
SquaresOfSum = pow(count,2);
cout<<SquaresOfSum-SumOfSquares;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Javascript**

```
const sumSquareDifference = (n) => {
  const numbers = [...Array(n + 1).keys()];
  const sumOfSquares = numbers.reduce((accumulator, number) => accumulator + (number ** 2));
  const squareOfSum = numbers.reduce((accumulator, number) => accumulator + number) ** 2;
  return squareOfSum - sumOfSquares;
}
console.log(sumSquareDifference(10));
```